# Webcam fire Flash effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any source code available in ActionScript3 that does something like this: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2005/11/flash_8_webcam_1.html

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/webcam-motion-detection-tracking

The link above isn't exactly what you're looking for but similar.  You could probably grab the original processing.org IDE which comes with samples, one is a webcam background differencing program, you can probably copy the algorithm from there if you're having trouble coming up with something yourself.  Using flash BitmapData methods and tweaking blendModes with a couple of frames can get some interesting stuff going.